# Htmlunit button won't submit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
public void actionVote() {
    HtmlForm form = this.page.getForms().get(0);
    HtmlInput button = form.getInputByValue("vote");
    try {
        button.click();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i do println with button.asText(), it gives me the correct value of the submit button, but when I do button.click, nothing happens, like it doesn't submit the form.

I can't get the button using HtmlButton because the submit button doesn't have any id or name.
I also can't make it HtmlButton from HtmlInput.

Why doesn't this submit? Wrong element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - **getInputByName** or **getButtonByName**

```
HtmlForm form = this.page.getForms().get(0);
HtmlInput button = form.getInputByName("vote");
```

Or you can also create a fake button:

```
HtmlElement fakeButton = page.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("type", "submit");

// add the button to the form
form.appendChild(fakeButton );
fakeButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code:

```
HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);

HtmlElement input = form.getElementsByAttribute("input", "name", "vote").get(0);

page =  input.click();
```

Comment: Hello user2115021, I have edited a number of your answers so that your code is displayed as code blocks. [Check this out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/232145) to see how you can do this formatting. It makes your posted code much easier to read.